# detecting scrollbar if is visible when Resizing Mat-table

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

i looked a lot for what i have to do but it seems i didn't found rigth solution. I have a mat-table.

```
<table
        mat-table
        *ngIf="data.length > 0"
        [dataSource]="data"
        class="default-table"
        matSort
        matSortStart="desc"
        (matSortChange)="sortData($event)"            
    >
```

So, i need to detect when the user resize the screen and horizontal scrollbar appears. When it happens, i have to do some changes in the table like to shade some columns.

I tried to do with a reference in the html and making a ViewChild without success. Do you have any ideas? I hope i was clear with my problem.

Thanks

Comment: I recall doing something similar. Basically you have to take the width of the whole scolling container and then width of the visible section. Then listen to resize event and check the widths to see if there is scrollbar or not.

Comment: With 'listen to resize' you mean to listen to windows resize? i'm trying to listen to table resize. Do you think it is posible?

Comment: Try using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver

Comment: your ViewChild is read:ElementRef? `@ViewChild('table',{read:ElementRef}) elTable:ElementRef`. I think that then, this.elTable.nativeElement is the html element.

Comment: @AdithyaSreyaj, I use rxjs fromEvent: `fromEvent(window,'resize').subscribe(res=>...)`

Comment: @Eliseo I would also go for `fromEvent` for listening to window resize events. But since author mentioned about listening to table resizing, I recommended `ResizeObserver`.